# Charles Proxy - Unable to Map Remote

Tags: macos, proxy, webpack-dev-server, charles-proxy

Basically I want to replace production client.js with https://localhost:3000/static/js/client.js

Localhost is running on webpack dev server.

Enabled SSL Proxy with *.

[image: Map to remote]

And chrome is showing pending status in development tools when Map Remote is turned on.

[image]